# How to show a UIPageControl on top of a fullscreen ChildViewController?

Tags: uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

In many apps' introduction screens, you have a UIPageControl that sits on top of a fullscreen image (no black border at the bottom).

I can not figure out how this is done.  Am I correct that the UIPageControl is added as a subview of the ChildViewController?  how does the pagecontrol not move once the user swipes to the next screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a UIPageViewController as your main screen. Implement

```
-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc {
    //
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc {
    // 
}
```

in your page view controller data source. (See the documentation to learn what you need to return for each of those methods.) The page control will magically appear, as part of the page view controller, simply because you implemented those methods.

Unfortunately it is difficult to see the UIPageControl, because the default is white on white! What I do is to color it with the appearance proxy. For example:

```
UIPageControl* proxy = [UIPageControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPageViewController class], nil];
[proxy setPageIndicatorTintColor:[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6]];
[proxy setCurrentPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[proxy setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

If you don't want to use a page view controller, you can add the UIPageControl directly. As you rightly say, it can't be a child of a *child* view controller, since it would then vanish when we switch to a different child. It has to be a child of the *parent* view controller, sitting in front of everything.